# Using jQuery in Google Chrome extension popup.html

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a working Google Chrome extension, which I'm attempting to extend with an additional feature.

I've amended the "popup.html" to include external references to jQuery, which are:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I've written corresponding controller-model methods in CodeIgniter to handle the jQuery requests, which are used elsewhere in the application, and are working:

```
$(document).ready($(function(){
    $('#link').autocomplete({
        source: "http://domain.com/topics/jq_get_topics_by_search_as_object/",
        appendTo: ".link-results",
        open: function(event, ui) {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete#link')
                .removeAttr('style')
                .hide()
                .appendTo('.link-results')
                .show();
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.link-results')
                .append('<div class="topic-link-box" id="topic-link-box-' + ui.item.topic_id + '"><input type="checkbox" id="topic-link-item-' + ui.item.topic_id + '" name="topic-links-add[]" value="' + ui.item.topic_id + '" checked="checked"><a href="' + 'http://macbookpro.local/development/theundercloud/topics/edit/' + ui.item.topic_id + '" title="Edit ' + ui.item.name + '">' + ui.item.name + '</a> [<a href="' + 'http://macbookpro.local/development/theundercloud/topics/view/' + ui.item.topic_id + '">View</a>] [<a href="' + 'http://macbookpro.local/development/theundercloud/topics/visit/' + ui.item.topic_id + '" target="_blank">Link</a>]</div>');
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>')
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>')
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
}));
```

Also, I've wrapped it in $(document).ready() method, which is the only substantial change to what I have working within the application itself.

And in addition to the jQuery references in "popup.html", I also have:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Topics</legend>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="link">Link</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="link" /></dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Which is external to the main form which handles the actual submission of data, within which I have:

```
<div class="link-results"></div>
```

Needless to say, this arrangement is — as far as I'm aware and able to test — identical to the working version within the application itself. However, it's not working within the Google Chrome extension.

**Update**

I've since found that there are errors with the Content Security Policy:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com".
Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com".
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I've changed the "manifest.json" to:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "file:///*/*",
    "https://*.google.com/"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
```

And I've changed the script references to the jQuery with Google to "https", but it's not fixed things.

Any ideas?

**FIXED**

I changed the URLs in the "manifest.json" to the same ones as found in the script references.

Comment: By dropping an alert() in the "popup.js" and seeing it work (although briefly, before being intercepted by Google Chrome, presumably), and then doing the same in "topics.js" within the code and not seeing anything, it appears that the code isn't working. Although, if I use the alert() on its own, it works.

Comment: You need `script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'`, if you want to use a CDN at all. I strongly recommend to bundle jQuery with your extension. There's no additional cost, and it causes your popup to load faster.

Comment: Hi Rob, I figured it out a short while ago. I just returned to explain the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the URLs in the "manifest.json" to the same ones as found in the script references, just as Rob pointed out a short while ago.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the security model of web browsers would stop you from loading a javascirpt page from a insecure source like a plug in dynamically. Also per some of the extension plug in documentation all JS files muse exist in the extension https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#relative-urls.

So simple answer is to download a version of [JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and include it in your project. Tested and worked for me.